# Assert array Values [Symfony] [Api-platform]

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I need to validate an array. And I also have to validate the values in this array.

For example I want to validate each of these entries and only this one. If I have anything else I want an error. But I can send only one entry if I want. How can I validate that?

```
"workDaysInput": [
    "full-week",
    "partial-week-3-4",
    "partial-week-1-2",
    "night-and-weekend"
],
```

Solved doing:
(thanks to @andrew-hutchings)

```php
#[Groups(['offer:write'])]
#[Assert\Count(min: 1)]
private array $workDaysInput;

/**
 * @Assert\Callback
 */
public function validate(ExecutionContextInterface $context, $payload)
{
    $workDays = $this->getWorkDaysInput();

    $allowedDays = [
        "full-week",
        "partial-week-3-4",
        "partial-week-1-2",
        "night-and-weekend"
    ];

    $violations = [];

    forEach($workDays as $day) {
        if (in_array($day, $allowedDays, true)) {
            continue;
        }


        $violations[] =
            $context->buildViolation(sprintf('Day selection %s not allowed', $day))
                ->atPath('workDays')
                ->addViolation()
            ;
    }

    if (count($violations) > 0) {
        return $violations;
    }
}
```

Comment: This *may* be of help when creating a custom validation on your array. "*Validation of arrays is possible using the Collection constraint*" [here from the docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/raw_values.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the context and where the array is used. But you can use the validation component. For more details see https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html

Here is a quick easy example if you are using an entity. if you need to do this validation in alot of places I recommend creating your own validation constraint. see here for the details
https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html

For this example we will use a callback constraint see https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html.

Add the following to your php file. When this class gets run through the validator it will read the annotation and run the validate function. Using a validation callback You will need to check each property individually and set the error for each constraint, in this example we are checking `workDaysInput`.

You will need to include the following use statements at the top of your class.

```php
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Context\ExecutionContextInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
```

```
/**
* @Assert\Callback
*/
public function validate(ExecutionContextInterface $context, $payload){
    $workDays = $this->getWorkDaysInput();
    $allowedDays = [
        "full-week",
        "partial-week-3-4",
        "partial-week-1-2",
        "night-and-weekend"
    ];

    if(count($workDays) < 1 && count($workDays) > 4) {
        return $context->buildViolation('Incorrect amount of options selected')
        ->atPath('workDays')
        ->addViolation();
    }

    forEach($workDays as $day){
        if(in_array($day, $allowedDays)) return $context->buildViolation(sprintf('Day selection %s not allowed', $day))
        ->atPath('workDays')
        ->addViolation();
    }
}
```